# How do I set up Sharepoint Alerts to be sent to distribution lists that include nondomain users?

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, distribution-lists

1) I would like to send Sharepoint Alerts to an email distribution list.

2) I would like that email distribution list to include domain and non-domain users.

3) I would like that email distribution list to be editable from Public Folders in exchange.

Is this possible?  It seems like it should be.

WSS 3.0 on Windows Server 2003 Standard

Just getting 1 and 2 would be a great start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the non-domain users as contacts in your AD and add them to your distribution list.

That'll enable sharepoint to hit internal as well as external users with alerts.

You can't easily manage the creation and deletion of these contacts through outlook although group membership can be managed through this - one way to restrict this could be creating a separate OU for the contacts and setting up access permissions on this, assuming you'd like someone else to be able to create them without full domain administrative access.

Answer (score 0):

I created an EMail address that forwards on to the distribution list.

Not perfect as leaves forwarded in the header but I can then OWA to that EMail to edit the forwarding rules.